# Late 70s early 80s tv movie or series

Tags: story-identification, tv

The main character is a young blonde (almost white) haired man who I think traveled from the future. He lands his craft near a hilly area by a small village. I think he has special superhuman powers and maybe a laser gun. It may have been only a TV movie. Anyone remember it?

Comment: It's not "The Phoenix", there's no laser gun, no ship, and he's not a time traveler, he's an ancient alien found in a pyramid. I thought it might be "The Flipside of Dominick Hyde"(1980 British TV movie), but he had no laser gun. We need more details as there are a lot of time travel TV movies and episodes.

Comment: Based on the description of the character and date there is an outside chance that this could be The Boy from Space. It was a british TV educational show. Here is a link to a clip of it on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zIbEoGRt-Q does it ring any bells?

Comment: Also there was definitely a scene where the villain causes a car to disappear by shooting at it with a "laser" gun. This is very low budget british TV and I recall the gun looked like a torch with a red coloured filter on the end! Sadly I can't find a clip of this on you tube.

Comment: I should also say that I'm sure there is no pyramid in this show or time travel. Is it possible that you are mixing up two shows? The time travel element could easily come from an episode of Doctor Who.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as no one else seems to have an answer I'll move this from the comments to the answers. I think this might be The Boy from Space, although its not a 100% fit. It was an educational series made in the mid 1970's that was then either expanded or refilmed (not sure exactly which) in about 1980. It features a tall blond character who is the villain, a blond child, referred to as Peep Peep who is the boy from space and the villain does indeed have a laser gun. Powers? Sadly I don't recall. Here are links to a clip on youtube and also the IMDB page for the Boy from Space. Does it ring any bells?

Here is the link to the IMDB page although there is not much information there. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0380093/

This was part of a series called Look and Read on the BBC and there was an accompanying book for the series. It is available on DVD and this link about the DVD mentions that the series was also edited into a feature length presentation which may be why you remember it as a film.

Finally there is a more detailed description of the story here. I don't own the DVD so can't say how accurate it is but it describes a space ship from Mars crashing on earth, a ray gun and a blond "thin man". No time travel but the spaceship crash may be what you remember. http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/%27The_Boy_From_Space%27_Aliens

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is neither the Phoenix or the Boy from Outer Space.  I'm fairly certain it was an American production and the main blonde actor was younger than the star of the Phoenix.